# Open window and send POST data

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building an Add-on that needs to open a window and send some for data (via POST) to a remote server. I can do either of those items fine - UrlFetchApp() for sending the data, and an anchor tag to open a new window, but I couldn't find a way to do both of them together.

Basically I need to send the user to another website temporarily and provide that website with some data entered within the Add-on. I tried doing this with pure javascript, but the window.open() method is not available within the GAS sandbox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible in apps script (and not possible in javascript either).
What you need is to open the external site with anchor & needed parameters (post data) in the url itself. Your external url in its javascript  must convert the params to a Post (or handle it directly in its server's Get)
Also, if the external page is for doing some authentication with callback (like oauth flow) apps script now support such 'oauth callbacks'

Comment: Thank you, Zig! That's no the answer I wanted to hear, but was afraid was the case. Thanks for confirming. Currently there is not an OAuth endpoint available for this function (or another callback-based process).

Comment: Yes apps script does have oauth callbacks now.